# Select configuration profile in an arquillian wildfly swarm test case

Tags: wildfly, jboss-arquillian, swarm

Is it possible to select a different `project-XXXX.yml` file to configure a swarm in an arquillian test case ?

I've tried with `@CreateSwarm` annotation an something like:

```
@CreateSwarm
static Swarm createSwarm() {
  Swarm s = new Swarm();
  s.setArgs("-SXXXX");
  return s;
}
```

But this doesn't work. I've also tryied with `.withConfig(url)` but I couldn't find any way to configure the `url` using class path resources (they simply aren't resolved in the project classpath) neither using relative paths in the project (the working dir is different during test setup/execution).

So I ended up in writing a temp config from a string into a file, converting it to an url and passing to the configuration, but I hope there's a better way. Personally I expected to simply have to add args to the `@DefaultDeployment` annotation; something like

```
....

@DefaultDeployment(withArgs=new String[] {"-S","XXXX"})
class MyTestCase {
  ....
}
```